# Puppet directory creation not resolving variables correctly

Tags: puppet

I am trying to create a directory based on a variable value. If the **$test**

Here is the content of my test.pp file:

```
$test = 'testDir123'

file {$test:
  path   => '/temp/$test',
  ensure => 'directory'
}
```

I would expect that after running **puppet apply test.pp** the **/temp/testDir123** would be created, however, a **/temp/$test** directory is being created instead.

I have used puppet variables before, to resolve URLs and user names.

I have tried other ways of writing that test manifest:

```
$test = 'testDir123'

file {$test:
  path   => '/temp/${test}',
  ensure => 'directory'
}
```

and 
    $test = '/temp/testDir123'

```
file {$test:
  path   => '${test}',
  ensure => 'directory'
}
```

but they all failed. It looks like the variable $test is not being resolved for some reason.

Comment: Use double-quotes for interpolation (details is [here](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_variables.html#interpolation)).

Comment: Well, that's great. It worked like a charm. Thanks.